# Deploy Python app to Heroku with extra pip install

Tags: python, heroku, pip, tornado

I'm trying to implement Deploy to Heroku functionality for my Python application:
https://github.com/jet-admin/jet-bridge/tree/heroku

It woks OK if just use requirements.txt to install dependencies, but it require me to modify my requirements.txt to include some extra packages that i normally don't need (psycopg2, mysqlclient).

Is it possible not to include all requirements in requirements.txt, but install it with some extra command? I've tried adding postdeploy script which will perform pip install command, but after deploy succed my application says that psycopg2 is not installed (thought i installed it in postdeploy command).

Comment: "it require me to modify my requirements.txt to include some extra packages that i normally don't need (psycopg2, mysqlclient)"—why don't you normally need those packages? What's different on Heroku? (Note that developing with one database engine and deploying to another is a generally bad idea. They're not drop-in replacements for each other.) I think the reason `postdeploy` isn't working is that it runs after your slug has already been compiled. Your libraries need to be included in the slug.

Comment: @Chris because by application is compatible with many databases thanks to ORM. so code in repository should not have all possible database adapters, but for application on heroku I need to include all of them, so that users can deploy it to Heroku and use it with their specific database. Is it possible to pip install somehow another way without including dep in requirements.txt ?

Comment: If you want it to be run on Heroku I think your only options are (a) to include all of those dependencies in `requirements.txt` (or in `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` if you would rather user Pipenv) or (b) to have your users modify those files before deploying.

Answer (score 0):

The [Heroku Python buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python) has [a hook where you can execute extra commands after the initial slug compilation](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/compile#L362).

To use it, you can add a `bin/post_compile` file, putting inside the shell commands for installing the extra packages.

You can even make it depend on an environment variable, like:

```
# assuming you have files mysql-requirements.txt and postgres-requirements.txt
if [ "$JET_BRIDGE_DB" == "mysql" ]; then
    echo  "Installing Python dependencies for MySQL support"
    pip install -r mysql-requirements.txt
else
    echo  "Assuming Postgres database, installing Python dependencies"
    pip install -r postgres-requirements.txt
fi
```

**Read more:**

- Buildpacks: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
- Heroku Python Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
- Slug compilation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler