# How do I deploy on Heroku a Python wrapper?

Tags: flask, heroku, web-applications

I am trying to deploy a [program](https://hal-stage.herokuapp.com/) on heroku. 
The program uses Flask and Python. It does not make any calls to a database.

It runs locally without an issue.

It builds successfully on heroku.

But when I interact with the web page, an AJAX call fails because it lacks a dependency. Error message:

`POST https://hal-stage.herokuapp.com/reason 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Inspecting the logs shows:

```
2020-02-29T23:45:05.133568+00:00 app[web.1]: raise InstallError('The SDD library is not available. Please install the PySDD package.')
2020-02-29T23:45:05.133574+00:00 app[web.1]: problog.errors.InstallError: The SDD library is not available. Please install the PySDD package..
```

The `PySDD` library is part of `requirements.txt`.

**How do I push to heroku the underlying SDD library?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add all dependencies on your pipfile, for example:

```
[[source]]

url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true


[packages]

Flask = "*"
PySDD = "*"

[requires]

python_version = "3.6"
```

Hope it suits well

Comment: Thanks, this helps somewhat. What if I want to deploy with a Python package on my computer that I compiled from source? How do I upload that folder (i.e. from site-packages)?

Comment: OP says they are using a `requirements.txt` file, which means `pip`, not Pipenv. If so, they should continue to use that file instead of adding a `Pipfile`. (If Heroku finds a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` it will completely ignore the `requirements.txt`, which could easily lead to other missing dependencies.)

Comment: @mac389 this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55302124/8969084) might give you some light about compiled packages on heroku.